# Php twilio make a call

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

i want write a demo use twilio with php,i have succee in useing offical demo like this

```
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
  $message = $client->account->calls->create(
    $accountData["From"],
    $accountData["To"],
    $accountData["voice-url"]
  );
```

$accountData["voice-url"] is a demo voice url,now i want say somthing different,i have no public server,so i can't make a restAPI,can i make a response in local?

```
<Reponse>
   <Say>hahahaha</Say>
</Reponse>
```

Comment: i have got another way to get a response from internet,twilio provide a method [enter link description here](http://www.twilio.com/labs),it solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We're [pretty huge fans of using a tool called ngrok](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/09/6-awesome-reasons-to-use-ngrok-when-testing-webhooks.html) to tunnel localhost to the outside world for this specific use case. Once you install ngrok you can run:

```
./ngrok http PORT_YOUR_LOCAL_SERVER_RUNS_ON
```

It'll spit out a publicly accessible URL that you can pass to Twilio when you initiate your call.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you for answering me .your method is a way to visit my localhost,but i  think it may sot suit me ,thanks anyway.

Comment: Sorry that wasn't what you were looking for. Another option you could try in addition to twimlets would be to use twimlbin.com to store your twiml.